# What happens if orchestration triggers a salt-master service restart?

Tags: salt-stack

Suppose I have an orchestration file that runs the salt-formula's salt.master state, among others. Suppose also that I've made some pillar change that results in an update to the master's config file, which in turn causes the salt-master service to restart.

What happens to the rest of the orchestration run? In particular, what happens if the config change is to something like GitFS remotes, where new files may be available to minions after the salt.master state runs?

Answer (score 1):

Once the salt master service restarts, a highstate stops dead in its tracks. There is no built in way to for a highstate to keep state across salt-master restarts. There are some workarounds where you set a flag on the file system or in a grain and have your highstate check for those flags.

That being said, if you're using the state.orchestrate or state.over runners, those aren't necessarily dependent on the salt-master daemon. I haven't tested this, but the state.orchestrate should most likely continue even if the salt-master daemon restarts.

I may have some time this afternoon to test, but I'd recommend just testing this in your environment.